# Creating an arc with set angle and range using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon

I'm currently using QGIS 3.6.

For a while now to map the arcs of fire for historical fixed weapon emplacements. Creating an arc to a set range to a set angle is extremely important for my analysis work.

I currently use the buffer tool to create a circular polygon around a point to the desired range and direction. I then have to essentially delete points until the desired angle is achieved. This isn't that precise, however as I have to estimate the correct angle. Doing this for every point is very time consuming and I was wondering if there was a quick and simple way to achieve the same result in QGIS, without manually setting the angle by deleting points and without plugins (if possible).

I am not a technical person and have no programming experience.

See below for an example of what I am hoping to achieve.

[image: Arc of fire to a range of 250m]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to me that this tool will do your work, see figure 1 [image]

and figure 2
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I was going to include the `create wedge buffers` tool in this answer, but @cyril beat me to it. Instead, I'll just mention several plugins that can create an arc or wedge, in case the `create wedge buffers` tool doesn't do quite what you wanted.

- Shape Tools Plugin

  > "Shape Tools is a collection of geodesic shapes and tools. Create ellipse, line of bearing, **pie wedge**, donut, **arc wedge**, polygon, star, ellipse rose, hypocyloid, polyfoil, epicycloid, and heart shapes. Tools include "XY to Line" tool, densify lines and polygons along geodesic paths, geodesic line break, geodesic measuring and create a measurement layer, geodesic scale, rotate, flip and translate tools, and digitize points at an azimuth & distance tools."
- Azimuth and Distance plugin

  > "Creates a feature from azimuths and distances"
- CoGo Plugin

  > "A plugin to capture coordinates, bearings and distances and to use these to construct and manage land parcels."