# Drawing concentric circles with different radii in QGIS

Tags: buffer

I have table that contain point data and multiple distance value for the point data in three different direction. I would like draw arc of 65degree in each of these three directions where the radius of the arc will vary according to a given distance data. It could  be in one direction I may have 5 arcs as only 5 distance values are non-zero and in another direcion i will have only 3 arcs as 3 values are non-zero. Is this possible ?

Comment: This answer will get you on track if you want to do it with geometry generator : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/229961/creating-sector-lights-in-qgis/230989#230989

Comment: Maybe this tool will solve your problem: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/315251/120129...QGIS 3.6

Answer (score 2):

There used to be a plugin for just this use case - for example, to draw **arc wedges** for things like nautical navigational beacons. I remember answering this question a few years ago but can't find it...

There is a plugin called **Shape Tools** - which seemingly has the ability to draw arc wedges. It might be worth a look. I've not tried this myself, but it's available in QGIS 3. Homepage is [here](https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/qgis-shapetools-plugin)

> Shape Tools is a collection of geodesic shapes and tools. Create ellipse, line of bearing, pie wedge, donut, arc wedge, polygon, star, ellipse rose, hypocyloid, polyfoil, epicycloid, and heart shapes. Tools include "XY to Line" tool, densify lines and polygons along geodesic paths, geodesic line break, geodesic measuring and create a measurement layer, geodesic scale, rotate, flip and translate tools, and digitize points at an azimuth & distance tools.

Comment: Thanks, will give it a try